# How to write regex to match URL;s?

Tags: regex

Im trying to write a regex to match the following URL's:

/jsp/offer/recr/us/wsj/recoffertemp2flow1.jsp?offerId=67700184&promoCode=4935003
/jsp/offer/recr/us/wsj/recoffertemp2flow1.jsp?offerId=67700185&promoCode=4935005
m/jsp/offer/recr/us/wsj/recoffertemp2flow1.jsp?offerId=67700189&promoCode=4935006

How would I do it? Basically the offerID and promoCode changes - but everything else is constant.

Thanks
Jake

Comment: Its for Optimizely, http://support.optimizely.com/customer/portal/articles/437323-how-can-i-specify-the-pages-on-which-my-experiment-should-run-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending upon the language you're using, the following regex should match these URLs and allow you to extract out the values for offerId and promoCode if you need to:

```
\/jsp\/offer\/recr\/us\/wsj\/recoffertemp2flow1.jsp\?offerId=(\d+)&promoCode=(\d+)
```

Comment: Ok - how would I exclude other URL's from this? THis looks like it will match any URL using this template.

Comment: Are you able to give an example of a URL you'd want excluding? I'm not able to check easily at the moment, but I'm pretty sure this regex only matches the URLs you've given as examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
^/jsp/offer/recr/us/wsj/recoffertemp2flow1\.jsp\?offerId=\d+\&promoCode=\d+$
```

But note that this regex would fail if you change the argument order.

Answer (score 0):

```
/jsp/offer/recr/us/wsj/recoffertemp2flow1\.jsp\?offerId=\d+&promoCode=\d+
```

You can match more URLs in addition to this by using the `(red|blue|green)` expression, e.g. `(/jsp/offer/recr...\d+|/second/URL/to/match|/third/URL/to/match)`, etc.

See [JavaScript RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for details on the syntax.